# How to check if the browser is Mist?

Tags: web3js, mist, nodejs, browsers

Whenever I want to use `web3`, I initialize it as follows:

```
if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
  web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
} else {
  // set the provider you want from Web3.providers
  web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
}
```

The provider works whether I'm in Mist or another browser (while `geth` is running locally). How can I distinguish between the two cases? Either in browser or server (maybe in `req` object of Node?), is there any way I can see if the user is using the Mist browser or not?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mist inserts a mist object you can check in the browser.

```
if (typeof(mist) !== "undefined") {
 // browser is running in mist
```